# batch file calling to function fail

Tags: windows, function, file, batch-file

been trying to figure how to make the random string generation as a function, then call to function to return new random for each for loop.

but unable to make it work...

blank of idea, batch programming seems lot more complicated than web..

```
@echo off

GOTO :MAIN

:TestFunc

    set orig=%1
    set %~2=%random%

goto :eof


:MAIN

    for %%a in (C:\folder\*.png) do (

        set /a count+=1
        set "fname=%%~a"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

        set param_to_function=LetItBeA
        call :TestFunc %param_to_function% return_value
        set random=%return_value%
        echo !random!

        echo !fname!

        ren "!fname!" img_%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%_%HR%%time:~3,2%-!random!.png

        endlocal
    )

goto :eof
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Original question answered (before edit). Explanation:

- Use `for /F` against `dir /b` as unlike `for /F`, `for` starts parsing files immediately so it could get a renamed file again and again...
- File renaming treated in a subroutine with test on file existence before `ren`.
- Note `endlocal&set "%1=%_RndAlphaNum%"&goto :eof` tricky part how-to  return a value to a variable (parameter) passed by reference.
- `ren` command `echo`ed merely for debugging purposes.

**Resources** (required reading):

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)

The script:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
Set /A "_RNDLength=6"
Set "_Alphanumeric=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"

set "_folder=C:\folder"
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B "%_folder%\*.png"') do (
    set /a count+=1
    set "fname=%%~nxa"
    call :renameFile
)
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:renameFile
call :getRandomString _RndANum
set "newFileName=img_%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%_%HR%%time:~3,2%-%_RndANum%.png"
if exist "%_folder%\%newFileName%" goto :renameFile
echo ren "%_folder%\%fname%" "%newFileName%"
goto :eof

:getRandomString
rem usage
rem call :getRandomString varname
rem %1 = a variable name (pass by reference)
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "_Str=%_Alphanumeric%987654321"
:_LenLoop
IF NOT "%_Str:~18%"=="" (
  SET _Str=%_Str:~9%
  SET /A "_Len+=9"
  GOTO :_LenLoop
)
SET _tmp=%_Str:~9,1%
SET /A _Len=_Len+_tmp
Set _count=0
SET _RndAlphaNum=
:_loop
Set /a _count+=1
SET _RND=%Random%
Set /A _RND=_RND%%%_Len%
SET _RndAlphaNum=!_RndAlphaNum!!_Alphanumeric:~%_RND%,1!
If !_count! lss %_RNDLength% goto _loop
rem do not split next line
endlocal&set "%1=%_RndAlphaNum%"&goto :eof
```

Comment: thanks for the resources, you a real genius, this solved my night mare and idea of what's wrong with mine.

Comment: In `echo ren "%_folder%\%fname%" "%newFileName%"`: remove leading `echo` no sooner than debugged...

Comment: yes, i found the echo after sending screenshot to you, should have go through clearly.  You are great.